# Data Structure for large and detailed maps

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, gis

Does anyone has recommendation of data structures for relative large maps with high resolution, something like 400mile x 400mile with 10-15ft resolution. Using 2D array, that would be roughly 2Mx2M cells.

The map only needs to store the elevation and terrain (earth, water, rock, etc.), and I don't think storing tiles is a good strategy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do with it: view it, store it, analyze it, etc...

One thing I can say, however, is that that file will be HUGE at your stated resolution, and you should consider splitting it up into at least a few tiles, even better at 1x1 mile tiles.

The list of [raster formats supported by GDA](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html)L could serve as a good starting point for exploring various formats, keeping in mind that many software packages (GRASS, ArcGIS, etc. use GDAL to read and write most raster formats). Note also that some file formats have maximum sizes which may prevent you from using them with your very large file.

For analysis and non-viewable storage, HDF5 format might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want people to see the data as a map over the web, then creating small image tile overlays will be the fastest approach to sharing such a large dataset.